Firebase error on authentication code that used to work fine
I am getting an error with this line in my SwiftUI app that uses Firebase:
self.userSession = Auth.auth().currentUser

The error is:
Value of type 'AuthViewModel' has no member 'userSession'
I get that same error in every place where I reference userSession. For example, in this line:
self.userSession = result.user

I have imported all of the packages into the app that I think I need:
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth

In fact, the code that is giving me this error is the exact same code that worked a few days ago. I did not change a single line in my code. It used to work fine. And now it doesn't.
I've tried closing down Xcode and openning the project back up and running it. I've tried Product -> Clean Build Folder several times. Under "Package Dependencies", I've tried "Update to Latest Package Versions", "Resolve Package Versions", and "Reset Package Caches". I updated to the latest version of Xcode. I even restarted my MacBook.
None of these things have resolved the error. I cannot start the same app that recently worked fine.
Edit: Here's the beginning part of the AuthViewModel (there are other parts to this class, but I do not think they are relevant to this error, which is for the line I specified above):
class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentUser: User?
    @Published var showInvalidUserCredentials: Bool = false
    
    @Published var errorMessage: String?
    @Published var showAlreadyExistingUserAlert = false

    var userNumber: Int = 0

    init() {
        self.userSession = Auth.auth().currentUser
        
        Task {
            await fetchUser()
        }
    }

    # additional
    # code
}


can you show the code for your AuthViewModel and where in your code you have self.userSession = Auth.auth().currentUser

I edited my post to include the relevant part of the AuthViewModel.

yes, I can see that the error message was correct 'AuthViewModel' has no member userSession. You probably wanted self.currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser. Or you need to add a @Published var userSession: ... or similar declaration.

AuthViewModel (which is self in this case) does not have a property userSession so why does the code attempt to assign currentUser to a property that doesn't exist? The class would need something along the lines of var userSession: User? for that statement to work.
